# Horizontal scroll with gridview

Tags: android

Now i have to create a horizontal listview again, this time i want to find a better library for this, as far as i know android did not have a horizontal listview, and then i read this

http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html

They mention if gridview can scroll horizontally, they even illustrated it with a picture. I try to find example of how to use gridview horizontally, but i have no luck,

is anyone here can help me how to use gridview scroll horizontally?

Comment: use the RecyclerView as you can do that with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm end up using recyclerview as @tyczj recommend

Answer (score 1):

This is the best library for two way grid. I have used it and it works perfectly.

https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: thanks for your recommendation, but the question is how to achieve this with original gridview from android like the link above